# Quiver/wind arrow plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot showing the wind direction and wind speed as a vector (arrow) on a map.

I have a dataset which has the following structure (consisting of several lines):

```
lat lon winddirection(degrees) windspeed(kts)

52 -12 270 32
51 -13 271 33
.
.
.
```

I tried to use the quiver module, however, this seems to work with u/v components.

Does anyone know how I would make a plot showing the wind as arrows on a lat/lon 2D map?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `winddirection` to compute `u, v` components like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# load your dataframe into the variable df

u = df["windspeed"] * np.cos(np.radians(df["winddirection"]))
v = df["windspeed"] * np.sin(np.radians(df["winddirection"]))
```

Then you do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(df["lat"], df["lon"], u, v, df["windspeed"], cmap=cm.viridis)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work if the wind direction is defined in degrees clockwise from the y-axis from the direction it originates, as is standard for meteorological wind direction, because matplotlib interprets the angle implied by u and v as being counter-clockwise from the x-axis and draws the arrows from tail to tip. To account for this, we need to explicitly pass values for the `angles` argument to `plt.quiver`, and convert  from meteorological degrees to mathematical degrees: `plt.quiver(df["lat"], df["lon"], u, v, df["windspeed"], angles=270-df["winddirection"]`.